# Roots of polynomial in an embedded field

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $f(x)$ be a polynomial of $degree > 0$ in $F[x]$. Show that there exists a field $F'$ and an embedding

$q: F ---> F'$

such that the polynomial $f^q$ $\in$  $F'[x]$ has a root in $F'$ where $f^q$ is obtained by replacing each coefficient $a$ of $f$ by $q(a)$.

Comment: $q$ could be the identity

Comment: But how do we get roots of f(x)?

Comment: What have you tried? This is a fundamental result that can be found in any book on field theory.

Comment: Is it because F[x] is an Euclidean Domain and hence a Unique Factorisation Domain, so f(x) is product of irreducible factors?